# jQuery Overuse of .add()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, addition

Is there a better approach to:

```
$(obj1).add(obj2).add(obj3).add(obj4)... etc?
```

I'm working on a script that has many user-optional components, and sometimes I'm needing to grab many of these. I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this, or if there's a way to pass in multiple objects into 1 .add? Also would it be worth it (e.g. if it involves building an array of objects then passing that in???)

Thanks!

Comment: "The argument to .add() can be pretty much anything that $() accepts, including a jQuery selector expression, references to DOM elements, or an HTML snippet.

Comment: $(obj1, obj2, obj4, etc) doesn't work..

Comment: @undefined looks good, but the second argument to a selector is the context; all others are ignored.  See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array of the objects:

```
$([obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]);
```

Comment: This creates an array of jQuery objects, not a merged one. `$( [ $("<a>"), $("<a>") ] )`.

Comment: This does work :) and is a lot easier to look at than a string of .add()s ... but is it more efficient?

Comment: @pimvdb I don't understand your criticism

Comment: @Aaron I wouldn't worry about efficiency right now unless your page is noticeably slow.  If I had to guess I would assume it's faster since each call to `.add` is an additional `jQuery` function call and that is probably more expensive.  I don't know for sure, though, and you can always benchmark: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: `$("<a>").add("<a>")` gives you a jQuery object consisting of two `a` elements. `$( [ $("<a>"), $("<a>") ] )` gives you a jQuery object, consisting of two nested jQuery objects. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/uMnWe/. No text is changed.

Comment: @pimvdb that would be different that the asker's example since `$("<"` performs the action of creating a DOM element.  Regardless, you seem to be incorrect: http://jsfiddle.net/WnXd3/

Comment: I've just done a benchmark running both situations inside a loop. The situation using chained .add functions was twice as slow. Thanks guys!

Comment: `.appendTo` works, `.text` does not. It is a coincidence. http://jsfiddle.net/WnXd3/1/

Comment: @pimvdb I understand now; I thought that it always returned a jQuery collection.  Why does `.appendTo` work and not `.text`?

Comment: @Explosion Pills: I don't know, but the array syntax is not in the documentation, I believe. So it's not supposed to work reliably.